# Forbid git svn local branch from committing to the remote svn repository

Tags: git-svn

I'm using git-svn to handle and commit to a svn repository.
I also have created a local branch with commits that I don't want to be committed to the repository.

For safety, I want that branch to be able to do "git svn rebase" but "git svn dcommit" should fail (it doesn't have to be a pretty solution, I just want to make sure that the commits in that branch do not get committed by mistake).

Is there a way to setup the local branch like this ?